# Customize table of content in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, table-of-contents

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer shows that by adding the following in preamble, we can put the table of contents at the beginning of each section and highlight the title of the current section:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

How can one do the following customization:
Change the font size of the **highlited current section title**, making it larger than other titles in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can control the size of the section in the toc via the `section in toc` and `section in toc shaded` font templates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\Huge}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc shaded}{size=\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

[image]